# What is the cardinality of $X=\{ \alpha \text{ ordinal }| \alpha\text{ is the order type of } A \subset \mathbb R\}$?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

I found out that $\aleph_1$ is an upper bound. I can show that any well ordered subset of $ \mathbb R$ is countable, so its order type is an element of $\omega_1$. I'd like to show that $|X|= \aleph_1$, but I don't know how to do it. Some hint?

Comment: In fact, every conutable ordinal can be embedded into $\mathbb{Q}$. We can prove that every countable linearly oredered set is embedded into $\mathbb{Q}$ by [back-and-forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method).

Comment: @HanulJeon  Nitpick: You need "back-and-forth" to prove that every countable dense linear order with no first or last element is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb Q.$ To prove that every countable linear order is *embeddable* in $\mathbb Q$ you don't need "back-and-forth", just "forth".

Comment: @bof. We can also avoid model theory altogether and use elementary means (and more time!).   The result that a non-empty dense countable linear order without end-points is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ is due to Cantor in the 19th century. And it is easy to embed any other countable linear  into such an order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try proving that any countable ordinal $\alpha$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}$ by induction on $\alpha$.  You'll make use of the countability assumption at limit stages, in that any countable limit ordinal has countable cofinality.

Alternatively, you can prove that any countable totally ordered set $X$ at all embeds in $\mathbb{R}$, by enumerating the elements of $X$ and defining an embedding $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ on one element at a time.

Comment: Alternatively, you can prove that any countable totally ordered set $X$ embeds in $\mathbb R$ by choosing an injection $\varphi:X\to\mathbb N$ and defining an embedding $f:X\to\mathbb R$ by writing $$f(x)=\sum_{y\lt x}2^{-\varphi(y)}.$$

Comment: @bof Do you know of a way to modify your embedding to ensure the range is contained in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Nope.